# Can't change CSS with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a page that first displays a red rectangle and a button. If you press the button the rectangle will change to blue square. Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>



    <style>
        #e1 {
            background-color: red ;
            width: 400px ;
            height: 200px ;
            margin: 0 auto;

        }
        .wrapper {
            text-align: center;
        }

    </style>


</head>

<body>


    <div id ="e1">
    </div>



    <div class="wrapper">
    <button type="button" onclick="myfunction()" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; position:center;">Switch</button>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myfunction() {
            document.getElementById("e1").style.background-color= "blue";
            document.getElementById("e1").style.width = "400px";
            document.getElementById("e1").style.height = "400px";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is the rectangle doesn't change to square that means the JavaScript has some issues.

Comment: add an event listener on button

Comment: `document.getElementById("e1").style.background-color= "blue";` is a syntax error. Do it like `document.getElementById("e1").style['background-color']= "blue";`

Comment: even thow if i replace what is inside my function with alert it alerts it so the problem is with this code : document.getElementById("e1").style.background-color= "blue";
        document.getElementById("e1").style.width = "400px";
        document.getElementById("e1").style.height = "400px";

Comment: when you say `style.background-color`, it is interpreted as you're subtracting `color` from `style.background`

Comment: try `document.getElementById("e1").style.backgroundColor` instead of background-color

Comment: your missing oening tag for button

Comment: same problem with this ['background-color']

Comment: it worked so the problem was with style.background-color it is javascript so it should be style.backgroundColor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
document.getElementById("e1").style.background-color= "blue";
```

To:

```
document.getElementById("e1").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
```

Answer (score 2):

This Should work

```
 document.getElementById("e1").style['background-color']= "blue";
```

Answer (score 2):

Two things -

First you have syntax error in

`document.getElementById("e1").style.background-color= "blue";`

It should be either

`document.getElementById("e1").style['background-color']= "blue";`

OR

`document.getElementById("e1").style.backgroundColor= "blue";`

Second, I don't know if it's a type in your question, but you missed the opening `<` in your button tag. That is the reason it is failing.

What you have here is

`button type = "button" onclick = "myfunction()" style = "width: 100px ; hight: 100px ; position:center ;">Switch</button>`

Which should be

`<button type = "button" onclick = "myfunction()" style = "width: 100px ; hight: 100px ; position:center ;">Switch</button>`

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/AdityaParab/nhqdbLus/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. There was a slight problem with your HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>



    <style>
        #e1 {
            background-color: red ;
            width: 400px ;
            height: 200px ;
            margin: 0 auto;

        }
        .wrapper {
            text-align: center;
        }

    </style>


</head>

<body>


    <div id ="e1">
    </div>



    <div class="wrapper">
    <button type = "button" onclick = "myfunction()" style = "width: 100px ; hight: 100px ; position:center ;">Switch</button>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myfunction() {
            document.getElementById("e1").style.backgroundColor= "blue";
            document.getElementById("e1").style.width = "400px";
            document.getElementById("e1").style.height = "400px";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Two things.

1. Complete your button tag. It was missing the initial "<" before "button".
2. Change background-color to backgroundColor in your JavaScript click handler.